# Show topology of pointwise convergence defines topology

Tags: general-topology

> Let $C(S)$ be the set of all bounded and continuous functions $f:S\to \mathbb{R}$ where $S\subset \mathbb{R}$. A function $f_0$ is interior in $\mathcal{E}\subset C(S)$  if there exists a finite subset $F$ of $S$ and and $\epsilon>0$ such that 
>   $\{f\in C(s): \vert \ f(x)- f_0(x)\vert<\epsilon \ \forall x \in F\} \subset \mathcal{E}$.

I am stuck with proving that the intersection of finitely many open sets is also an open set. My initial thought was to try taking the minimum of all the epsilons and the intersection of all $F$s, yet this does not work, as the intersection may be empty. How can I prove this instead?

Comment: a *non-empty* finite set...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a subbase $\mathcal{S}$ consisting of all sets $S(f_0,\varepsilon, p) =\{f\in C(S): |f(p) - f_0(p)| < \varepsilon \}$ where $f_0 \in C(S)$, $p \in S$, $\varepsilon > 0$, a real number. Then your basic sets (in a similar notation to mine) $S(f_0, \varepsilon ,F) = \cap_{p \in F} S(f_0, \varepsilon, p)$ are finite intersections of these subbase elements. So $\mathcal{T}(\mathcal{S})$ (the topology generated by this subbase) contains all your basic open sets, and has all finite intersections of subbasic elements as its standard base (we need to check it doesn't give more open sets), and if $g \in \mathcal{E}$ is interior wrt the topology $\mathcal{T}(\mathcal{S})$, then we have the situation that

$$g \in S(f_0, \varepsilon_0, p_0) \cap S(f_1, \varepsilon_1, p_1) \cap \ldots S(f_n, \varepsilon_n, p_n) \subset \mathcal{E}$$

using the base from the subbase.
Then we define $\delta_i = \varepsilon_i - |f_0(p_i) - g(p_i)| > 0$
Set $\delta = \min\{\delta_i: i = 0 ,\ldots n\} > 0$, $F = \{p_0, \ldots, p_n\}$

and we note that

$$g \in S(g, \delta, F) \subseteq S(f_0, \varepsilon_0, p_0) \cap S(f_1, \varepsilon_1, p_1) \cap \ldots S(f_n, \varepsilon_n, p_n) \subset \mathcal{E}$$

making it interior for "your" topology as well. So the subbase and your base define the same topology (the have equivalent local bases and the same interior points). It's a topology because it's just the topology generated by $\mathcal{S}$

This subbase corresponds with a subbase for the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^S$, as $$S(f_0, \varepsilon, p) = \pi_p^{-1}[(f_0(p)  -\varepsilon, f_0(p) + \varepsilon)] \cap C(S)$$ So we see that the pointwise convergence topology is just the inherited topology from $\mathbb{R}^S$ on $C(S)$.

Answer (score 0):

You want the minimum over all the epsilons and the union of all the $F$'s.

The condition for $f$ being in a basis neighborhood $U_i$ of $f_0$ is that $f$ is $\epsilon_i$ close to $f_0$ at the finite collection of points $F_i$. If $f$ is $\epsilon = \min_i \epsilon_i$ close to $f_0$ at all of the points in $F = \bigcup_i F_i$, then $f \in \bigcap_i U_i$.

Comment: Thank you. When I was considering taking the union, I was not too sure about that. This was because we look for an $F_i$ and $\epsilon_i$  per function $f_{i}\in U_{i}$. But this means that it is not needed that $F_i \cap F_j\neq\emptyset$ if $i\neq j$, but  the $\epsilon_i$ is 'dependent' on the subset $F$. Why does it work nevertheless?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you clarify?