# Show that this family of open sets forms a topology of pointwise convergence

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, pointwise-convergence

This is Exercise 22.12 (b) on page 185 of *Elementary Analysis*, second edition, written by Kenneth Ross. I searched the site for similar questions and found a couple that looked similar ([this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3594375/the-proof-of-the-topology-of-pointwise-convergence) and particularly [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2189807/show-topology-of-pointwise-convergence-defines-topology)), but neither of those questions match mine in scope, and the language and notation used are too advanced. I am about halfway through a book called "Elementary Analysis" and I think that is a reasonable description of my mathematical skill set in regards to this question. (In other words, I don't even understand real analysis very well, so I know essentially nothing about topology.)

**Background**

Let $S$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Let $C(S)$ be the set of all bounded continuous real-valued functions on $S$. For $f, g \in C(S)$, let $d(f, g) = \sup \{ \lvert f(x) - g(x) \rvert \colon x \in S \}$. This makes $\big( C(S), d \big)$ a metric space.

Now I quote from Exercise 22.12 (b):

> 22.12 Consider a subset $\mathcal{E}$ of $C(S), S \subseteq   \mathbb{R}$. For this exercise, we say a function $f_0$ in $\mathcal{E}$ is *interior* to $\mathcal{E}$ if there exists a finite subset $F$ of $S$ and an $\epsilon > 0$ such that
>
> $\{ f \in C(S) \colon \lvert f(x) - f_0 (x) \rvert < \epsilon \text{ for } x \in F \} \subseteq \mathcal{E}$.
>
> The set $\mathcal{E}$ is *open* if every function in $\mathcal{E}$ is interior to $\mathcal{E}$.
>
> (b) Show the family of open sets defined above forms a topology for $C(S)$.

From Discussion 13.7 on page 87, I gather that I need to show

> 1. $C(S)$ is open in $C(S)$.
> 2. The empty set $\emptyset$ is open in $C(S)$.
> 3. The union of any collection of open sets is open.
> 4. The intersection of finitely many open sets is again an open set.

**My attempt**

1. Consider $f_0 \in C(S)$. We want to show that there exists a finite subset $F$ and $\epsilon > 0$ such that

   $\{ f \in C(S) \colon \lvert f(x) - f_0(x) \rvert < \epsilon \text{ for } x \in F \} \subseteq C(S)$.

   It seems to me that any $F$ and $\epsilon$ will suffice here.
2. Consider $f_0 \in \emptyset$. (Bear with me.) We want to show that there exists a finite subset $F$ and $\epsilon > 0$ such that

   $\{ f \in C(S) \colon \lvert f(x) - f_0(x) \rvert < \epsilon \text{ for } x \in F \} \subseteq \emptyset$.

   **Question** This is nonsense as stated. How do I conclude that $\emptyset$ is open? I would say: there are no functions in $\emptyset$. So the set of functions in $C(S)$ that are within $\epsilon$ of some non-existent function on some finite set is empty. Therefore $\emptyset \subseteq \emptyset$. Is that right?
3. Consider open sets $\mathcal{E}_1, \mathcal{E}_2, \mathcal{E}_3, \dots$ and $f_0 \in \bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty} \mathcal{E}_i$. (We can presumably recover the finite case by letting $\mathcal{E}_n = \emptyset$ for all $n$ greater than some $N$.) We want to show that there exists a finite subset $F$ and $\epsilon > 0$ such that

   $\{ f \in C(S) \colon \lvert f(x) - f_0(x) \rvert < \epsilon \text{ for } x \in F \} \subseteq \bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty} \mathcal{E}_i$.

   Consider any one $\mathcal{E}_i$ such that $f_0 \in \mathcal{E}_i$. (We know there is at least one such $\mathcal{E}_i$.) This $\mathcal{E}_i$ has a corresponding $F$ and $\epsilon$, call them $F_i$ and $\epsilon_i$. We can use $F_i$ and $\epsilon_i$ to show that the set above in curly brackets is a subset of $\mathcal{E}_i$, which means it's in the infinite union.
4. Consider open sets $\mathcal{E}_1, \dots, \mathcal{E}_n$ and $f_0 \in \bigcap_{i = 1}^n \mathcal{E}_i$. We want to show that there exists a finite subset $F$ and $\epsilon > 0$ such that

   $\{ f \in C(S) \colon \lvert f(x) - f_0(x) \rvert < \epsilon \text{ for } x \in F \} \subseteq \bigcap_{i = 1}^n \mathcal{E}_i$.

   There exist $F_1, \dots, F_n$ and $\epsilon_1, \dots, \epsilon_n$ such that

   $\{ f \in C(S) \colon \lvert f(x) - f_0(x) \rvert < \epsilon_1 \text{ for } x \in F_1 \} \subseteq \mathcal{E}_1$.

   $\vdots$

   $\{ f \in C(S) \colon \lvert f(x) - f_0(x) \rvert < \epsilon_n \text{ for } x \in F_n \} \subseteq \mathcal{E}_n$.

   It seems intuitively clear that $\epsilon = \min \{\epsilon_1, \dots, \epsilon_n \}$ will work. **Question** What do I do for $F$? I thought about using $F = \bigcap_{i = 1}^n F_i$ but I have a feeling that is wrong because I have no assurance the intersection contains anything. I thought about using $F = \bigcup_{i = 1}^n F_i$ but how do I know that any function $f$ will actually be within $\min \{\epsilon_1, \dots, \epsilon_n \}$ of $f_0$ over all elements of $\bigcup_{i = 1}^n F_i$? I guess worst case, only $f_0$ meets that criterion? In that case we could say $\{ f_0 \} \subseteq \bigcap_{i = 1}^n \mathcal{E}_i$.

**Final comment**

Sorry for such a long post. I am trying to be thorough and provide relevant background. I have no intuition for what I am doing in this exercise---I am just manipulating symbols. Is there any intuition for this topic that can be provided to someone at my mathematical level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $(1)$ is fine.

$(2)$ is vacuously true: there is no $f\in\varnothing$, so there is nothing to be verified.

In $(3)$ you cannot assume that the collection of open sets is countable: the union of **any** collection of open sets must be open. Let $\Bbb E$ be a family of open sets, and let $\mathscr{U}=\bigcup\Bbb E$; we want to show that $\mathscr{U}$ is open. To that end let $f\in\mathscr{U}$; then there is an $\mathscr{E}\in\Bbb E$ such that $f\in\mathscr{E}$, which by definition means that there are a finite $F\subseteq S$ and $\epsilon>0$ such that

$$\{g\in C(S):|g(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon\text{ for each }x\in F\}\subseteq\mathscr{E}\;.$$

But $\mathscr{E}\subseteq\mathscr{U}$, so $\{g\in C(S):|g(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon\text{ for each }x\in F\}\subseteq\mathscr{U}$, and therefore $\mathscr{U}$ is open.

In $(4)$ your choice of $\epsilon$ is fine, but you want to take $F=\bigcup_{i=1}^nF_i$, the **union** of the finite sets $F_i$. Then for any $f\in C(S)$ and any $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ you have

$$\begin{align*}
&\{f\in C(S):|f(x)-f_0(x)|<\epsilon\text{ for each }x\in F\}\tag{1}\\
\subseteq\;&\{f\in C(S):|f(x)-f_0(x)|<\epsilon_i\text{ for each }x\in F_i\}\tag{2}\\
\subseteq\;&\mathscr{E}_i\;,
\end{align*}$$

which is exactly what you want. The point is that by making $\epsilon$ at least as small as each $\epsilon_i$ and making $F$ at least as big as each $F_i$, you are ensuring that the restrictions defining the set in $(1)$ are at least as strong as those in $(2)$ that are needed to ensure that all of the functions in the set that you’re defining are also in the set $\mathscr{E}_i$.

Comment: "...to ensure that all of the functions in the set that you’re defining are also in the set $\mathscr{E}_i.$" Since this is true for any $i$, it must be true for the intersection. I think I've got it. Two questions: 1) I am not familiar with uncountable unions. Is the way you made the union (the union of families of sets) the way it's normally done? Would it be improper to write something like $\bigcup_{r \in \mathbb{R}} \mathcal{E}_r$? 2) Is what I wrote near the end of my question (about how "worst case", $f_0$ might be the only function meeting the more stringent criteria) true?

Comment: @Novice: Yes, it’s one very standard way: if $\mathscr{A}$ is a collection of sets, $\bigcup\mathscr{A}$ is the union of the sets in that collection, so for any $x$ we have $x\in\bigcup\mathscr{A}$ if and only if there is at least one $A\in\mathscr{A}$ such that $x\in A$. It wouldn’t be right to write $\bigcup_{r\in\Bbb r}\mathscr{E}_r$ unless you knew that you were taking the union of sets that were already indexed by the real numbers. What you **could** do is consider $\bigcup_{i\in I}\mathscr{E}_i$, where $I$ is some (unspecified) index set, and each $\mathscr{E}_i$ is an open set.

Comment: @Novice: You know that $f_0$ meets the requirements to belong to that set. Whether any other functions meet them really doesn’t matter: that set is by definition open, it contains $f_0$, and it’s a subset of $\bigcap_{i=1}^n\mathscr{E}_i$, and that’s all that we need. Is it actually possible that it’s really just $\{f_0\}$? No: there is no $S\subseteq\Bbb R$ for which that would be possible.